# Encode URL in page.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, pushstate

Is there a way to encode a URL by default while using [page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/)

For example:

`<a href="/some link">Click</a`

This gives `http://example.com/some link` in the address bar instead of `http://example.com/some%20link`.

To achieve this you need to do

`<a href={encodeURI('/some link')}>click</a>`

Is there any other work around?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to mention the url in this form:

```
<a href="some_link">Click</a>
```

Which will mean
http://example.com/some_link